# No route matches [POST] "/posts/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm still trying to figure how routes work on rails. What I like to happen is when user submitted a form with image, it will show the image on index page.

Index:

```
<%= @posts.each do |x| %>
  <div class="white">
   <%= image_tag post.image_url(:medium) %>
   <br />
   <%= x.description %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

new:

```
<%= simple_form_for @post, url: root_path, as: 'new post',
  wrapper_mappings: {
    check_boxes: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes,
    radio_buttons: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes,
    file: :vertical_file_input,
    boolean: :vertical_boolean
  } do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>
  <%= f.input :image, as: :file %>
  <br>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Show:

```
<%= image_tag(@posts.image.url(:medium)) %>
    <%= @posts.description %>
```

Here's is my github if anyone could help me out: https://github.com/mahalocode/insta

Thanks in advance
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<%= simple_form_for @post,
  wrapper_mappings: {
    check_boxes: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes,
    radio_buttons: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes,
    file: :vertical_file_input,
    boolean: :vertical_boolean
  } do |f| %>
```

I don't know your intention behind the use of `:as and :url`. Please refer this cheat sheet to know more about these options. 
[cheat sheet](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/wiki/4.1-Options-Cheat-Sheet#input)

I made some other changes and pushed the code into your github repository. Please take a pull.

Cheers!

Comment: Hey. now when I tried to submit. It got a different routing error:

Comment: No route matches [POST] "/"

Comment: Did you make any change in routes. rb?